# highcharts missing x axis labels when stacking two charts

Tags: highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/3p6FC/

I used demo candlestick/bar chart and with margin and spacing all set to 0 and the following set:

```
chart.height = 325

yAxis[0].height = 200
yAxis[1].height = 50
yAxis[1].top = 250
```

I thought that setting the height at 250 would give ample room for the x axis labels to render underneath. Unfortunately, they are not showing up. Can anyone provide insight as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set offset for xAxis:

```
        xAxis: {
            offset: -25 /* 325 - 250 - 50*/
        },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3p6FC/1/